# Specify directory with setwd()

Tags: r, working-directory

I understand that in R to set my working directory I can do:

```
setwd("~/dir1/dir2/mydir")
```

If mydir is a unique directory name, is there way to specify the working directory without stating dir1/dir2 ?

Thanks

Comment: I'm interpreting your question as wanting to have the computer automatically find the directory, which would probably be difficult.  You'd have to use some kind of system tool to search for the directory (which would be different, and might or might not exist, on Windows vs MacOS vs Linux).  On a properly set-up Linux system you might be able to use something like `setwd(system("locate mydirname",intern=TRUE))` ...

Answer (score 12, accepted):

`Sys.glob` does what you want:

```
setwd(Sys.glob("~/*/*/mydir"))
```

If you don't know how deep it's nested, you can use `list.files` or `dir`:

```
list.files(path="~", pattern="mydir", all.files=TRUE, full.names=TRUE,
  recursive=TRUE, ignore.case=FALSE, include.dirs=TRUE)
```

Comment: You should be able to construct a pattern that allows an arbitrary number of slashes before it finds "mydir". I wou;dn't want to set it loose on my device, though. I needed to interrupt my tests with `list.dirs()`.

Comment: I'm not sure about that ... http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#tag_18_13_03 doesn't seem to allow parenthesized subexpressions (e.g. `"~/(*/)+mydir"`