# read .csv file with unknown path -- R

Tags: r, path, design-patterns, dir

I know this might be very stupid question but I have been spending hours on this

want to read a .csv file that I dont have its full path (*/*data.csv). I know that following would get the path of the current directory but don't know how to adapt

```
Marks <- read.csv(dir(path = '.', full.names=T, pattern='^data.*\\.csv'))
```

tried this one as well but not working

```
Marks <- read.csv(file = "*/*/data.csv", sep = ",", header=FALSE))
```

I can't identify specific path as this will be used on different machines with different paths but I am sure about the sub-folders of the main directory as they are result of a bash script

and I am planing to call this from within unix which defines the workspace

my data structure is

```
lecture01/test/data.csv
lecture02/test/data.csv
lecture03/test/data.csv
```

Comment: Presumably you are on Linux / unix?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12324539/specify-directory-with-setwd/12324637#12324637

Comment: @Ricardo Saporta: I have both windows and linux

Comment: Is your CSV file always in a subdirectory of the current working directory?

Comment: @Carl Witthoft: yes ... I have few lecture folders, each have folder Marks, which contain the data.csv files

Comment: @Ben Bolker but that does not consider the setwd that I already have and returns the file in default dir ... i want to only get the ones which are in sub-folders of that specific folder

Comment: This question is very confusing to me. If the code will be run on different computers, but in situations where `setwd` will have already been run, then simply running `read.csv("subfolder/data.csv")` will get you to the right place regardless of the machine you're on. I don't understand what the problem is.

Comment: @joran: I want to create a loop around itlate to read them one by one for some more actions... learning step by step.. I have may folders with same structure, want to be able to read insider sub-folders... my files are like this (lecture01/marks/data.csv, lecture02/marks/data.csv, lecture03/marks/data.csv)

Comment: I'm sorry but this still makes absolutely no sense to me. I still see no clear statement of a concrete problem, just some vague references to reading csv's and path names.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your comments -- though not currently your question itself -- indicate you expect to run your code in a working directory that contains some number of subdirectories (lecture01, lecture02, etc), each of which contain a subdirectory 'marks' that in turn contains a data.csv file. If this is so, and your objective is to read the csv from within each subdirectory, then you have a couple of options depending on the remaining details.

**Case 1**: Specify the top-level directory names directly, if you know them all and they are potentially idiosyncratic:

```
dirs <- c("lecture01", "lecture02", "some_other_dir")
paths <- file.path(dirs, "marks/data.csv")
```

**Case 2**: Construct the top-level directory names, e.g. if they all start with "lecture", followed by a two digit number, and you are able to (or specifically wish to) specify a numeric range, e.g. 01 though 15:

```
dirs <- sprintf("lecture%02s", 1:15)
paths <- file.path(dirs, "marks/data.csv")
```

**Case 3**: Determine the top-level directory names by matching a pattern, e.g. if you want to read data from within every directory starting with the string "lecture":

```
matched.names <- list.files(".", pattern="^lecture")
dirs <- matched.names[file.info(matched.names)$isdir]
paths <- file.path(dirs, "marks/data.csv")
```

Once you have a vector of the paths, I'd probably use `lapply` to read the data into a list for further processing, naming each one with the base directory name:

```
csv.data <- lapply(paths, read.csv)
names(csv.data) <- dirs
```

Alternatively, if whatever processing you do on each individual CSV is done just for its side effects, such as modifying the data and writing out a new version, and especially if you don't ever want all of them to be in memory at the same time, then use a loop.

If this answer misses the mark, of even if it doesn't, it would be great if you could clarify the question accordingly.

Comment: thanx a lottttt...I might be asking wrong question as I am just trying to learn things.. check the link... it might give u better sense of what im trying to  achieve and why i though its good to read the file... [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15095196/loop-for-applying-script-to-sub-folders-and-name-results-accordingly-r)

Comment: whats the reason to have 'dirs <-matched.names[file.info(matched.names)$isdir]' ? because it works even without it

Comment: matched.names will include names of any directories *and* files matching the list.files pattern. This would be a problem if, for example, you also have a file called "lecture_notes.txt" in your working directory. The subsequent line extracts just the directory names. Sounds like this is (currently) unnecessary for you, but I'd still keep it in there as a defensive programming practice.

Answer (score 0):

I have no code but I would do a reclusive glob from the root and do a preg_match to find the .csv file (use glob brace).